# Python Libs conflicts while installing Ansible Tower 3.4.2

Tags: ansible-tower

Getting below error while installing Ansible tower, any idea how this can be resolved? Please help.

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "msg": "Error: Package: ansible-tower-server-3.4.2-1.el7.x86_64 (ansible-tower)\n           Requires: python-crypto\nError: python-libs conflicts with python-virtualenv-1.10.1-2.el7.noarch\n", "rc": 1, "results": ["Loaded plugins: distro-guard, enabled_repos_upload, package_upload, product-id,\n              : subscription-manager\nResolving Dependencies\n--> Running transaction check\n---> Package ansible-tower.x86_64 0:3.4.2-1.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: ansible-tower-ui = 3.4.2-1.el7 for package: ansible-tower-3.4.2-1.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: ansible-tower-server = 3.4.2-1.el7 for package: ansible-tower-3.4.2-1.el7.x86_64\n--> Running transaction check\n---> Package ansible-tower-server.x86_64 0:3.4.2-1.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: ansible-tower-venv-tower = 3.4.2-1.el7 for package: ansible-tower-server-3.4.2-1.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: ansible-tower-venv-ansible = 3.4.2-1.el7 for package: ansible-tower-server-3.4.2-1.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: supervisor >= 3.0 for package: ansible-tower-server-3.4.2-1.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: bubblewrap >= 0.1.2 for package: ansible-tower-server-3.4.2-1.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: xmlsec1-openssl for package: ansible-tower-server-3.4.2-1.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: xmlsec1 for package: ansible-tower-server-3.4.2-1.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: subversion for package: ansible-tower-server-3.4.2-1.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: rabbitmq-server for package: ansible-tower-server-3.4.2-1.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: python-crypto for package: ansible-tower-server-3.4.2-1.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: postgresql96 for package: ansible-tower-server-3.4.2-1.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: nginx for package: ansible-tower-server-3.4.2-1.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: mercurial for package: ansible-tower-server-3.4.2-1.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: memcached for package: ansible-tower-server-3.4.2-1.el7.x86_64\n---> Package ansible-tower-ui.x86_64 0:3.4.2-1.el7 will be installed\n--> Running transaction check\n---> Package ansible-tower-server.x86_64 0:3.4.2-1.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: python-crypto for package: ansible-tower-server-3.4.2-1.el7.x86_64\n---> Package ansible-tower-venv-ansible.x86_64 0:3.4.2-1.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: python-virtualenv for package: ansible-tower-venv-ansible-3.4.2-1.el7.x86_64\n---> Package ansible-tower-venv-tower.x86_64 0:3.4.2-1.el7 will be installed\n---> Package bubblewrap.x86_64 0:0.1.7-1.el7 will be installed\n---> Package memcached.x86_64 0:1.4.15-10.el7_3.1 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: libevent-2.0.so.5()(64bit) for package: memcached-1.4.15-10.el7_3.1.x86_64\n---> Package mercurial.x86_64 0:2.6.2-10.el7 will be installed\n---> Package nginx.x86_64 1:1.14.1-1.el7at will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: nginx-filesystem = 1:1.14.1-1.el7at for package: 1:nginx-1.14.1-1.el7at.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: nginx-all-modules = 1:1.14.1-1.el7at for package: 1:nginx-1.14.1-1.el7at.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: nginx-filesystem for package: 1:nginx-1.14.1-1.el7at.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libprofiler.so.0()(64bit) for package: 1:nginx-1.14.1-1.el7at.x86_64\n---> Package postgresql96.x86_64 0:9.6.6-1PGDG.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: postgresql96-libs(x86-64) = 9.6.6-1PGDG.el7 for package: postgresql96-9.6.6-1PGDG.el7.x86_64\n---> Package rabbitmq-server.noarch 0:3.7.4-2.el7at will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: erlang >= 19.3 for package: rabbitmq-server-3.7.4-2.el7at.noarch\n--> Processing Dependency: socat for package: rabbitmq-server-3.7.4-2.el7at.noarch\n---> Package subversion.x86_64 0:1.7.14-11.el7_4 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: subversion-libs(x86-64) = 1.7.14-11.el7_4 for package: subversion-1.7.14-11.el7_4.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libsvn_wc-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.7.14-11.el7_4.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libsvn_subr-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.7.14-11.el7_4.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libsvn_repos-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.7.14-11.el7_4.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libsvn_ra_svn-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.7.14-11.el7_4.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libsvn_ra_neon-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.7.14-11.el7_4.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libsvn_ra_local-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.7.14-11.el7_4.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libsvn_ra-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.7.14-11.el7_4.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libsvn_fs_util-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.7.14-11.el7_4.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libsvn_fs_fs-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.7.14-11.el7_4.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libsvn_fs_base-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.7.14-11.el7_4.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libsvn_fs-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.7.14-11.el7_4.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libsvn_diff-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.7.14-11.el7_4.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libsvn_delta-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.7.14-11.el7_4.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libsvn_client-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.7.14-11.el7_4.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libneon.so.27()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.7.14-11.el7_4.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libaprutil-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.7.14-11.el7_4.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libapr-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.7.14-11.el7_4.x86_64\n---> Package supervisor.noarch 0:3.1.4-1.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: python-meld3 >= 0.6.5 for package: supervisor-3.1.4-1.el7.noarch\n---> Package xmlsec1.x86_64 0:1.2.20-7.el7_4 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: libxslt.so.1(LIBXML2_1.0.22)(64bit) for package: xmlsec1-1.2.20-7.el7_4.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libxslt.so.1(LIBXML2_1.0.11)(64bit) for package: xmlsec1-1.2.20-7.el7_4.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libxslt.so.1()(64bit) for package: xmlsec1-1.2.20-7.el7_4.x86_64\n---> Package xmlsec1-openssl.x86_64 0:1.2.20-7.el7_4 will be installed\n--> Running transaction check\n---> Package ansible-tower-server.x86_64 0:3.4.2-1.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: python-crypto for package: ansible-tower-server-3.4.2-1.el7.x86_64\n---> Package apr.x86_64 0:1.4.8-3.el7_4.1 will be installed\n---> Package apr-util.x86_64 0:1.5.2-6.el7 will be installed\n---> Package erlang.x86_64 0:20.3.8.9-3.el7at will be installed\n---> Package gperftools-libs.x86_64 0:2.4-8.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: libunwind.so.8()(64bit) for package: gperftools-libs-2.4-8.el7.x86_64\n---> Package libevent.x86_64 0:2.0.21-4.el7 will be installed\n---> Package libxslt.x86_64 0:1.1.28-5.el7 will be installed\n---> Package neon.x86_64 0:0.30.0-3.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_2_12)(64bit) for package: neon-0.30.0-3.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit) for package: neon-0.30.0-3.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libproxy.so.1()(64bit) for package: neon-0.30.0-3.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libpakchois.so.0()(64bit) for package: neon-0.30.0-3.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libgnutls.so.28()(64bit) for package: neon-0.30.0-3.el7.x86_64\n---> Package nginx-all-modules.noarch 1:1.14.1-1.el7at will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: nginx-mod-stream = 1:1.14.1-1.el7at for package: 1:nginx-all-modules-1.14.1-1.el7at.noarch\n--> Processing Dependency: nginx-mod-mail = 1:1.14.1-1.el7at for package: 1:nginx-all-modules-1.14.1-1.el7at.noarch\n--> Processing Dependency: nginx-mod-http-xslt-filter = 1:1.14.1-1.el7at for package: 1:nginx-all-modules-1.14.1-1.el7at.noarch\n--> Processing Dependency: nginx-mod-http-perl = 1:1.14.1-1.el7at for package: 1:nginx-all-modules-1.14.1-1.el7at.noarch\n--> Processing Dependency: nginx-mod-http-image-filter = 1:1.14.1-1.el7at for package: 1:nginx-all-modules-1.14.1-1.el7at.noarch\n--> Processing Dependency: nginx-mod-http-geoip = 1:1.14.1-1.el7at for package: 1:nginx-all-modules-1.14.1-1.el7at.noarch\n---> Package nginx-filesystem.noarch 1:1.14.1-1.el7at will be installed\n---> Package postgresql96-libs.x86_64 0:9.6.6-1PGDG.el7 will be installed\n---> Package python-meld3.x86_64 0:0.6.10-1.el7 will be installed\n---> Package python-virtualenv.noarch 0:1.10.1-2.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: python2-devel for package: python-virtualenv-1.10.1-2.el7.noarch\n---> Package socat.x86_64 0:1.7.3.2-2.el7 will be installed\n---> Package subversion-libs.x86_64 0:1.7.14-11.el7_4 will be installed\n--> Running transaction check\n---> Package ansible-tower-server.x86_64 0:3.4.2-1.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: python-crypto for package: ansible-tower-server-3.4.2-1.el7.x86_64\n---> Package gnutls.x86_64 0:3.3.29-8.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: trousers >= 0.3.11.2 for package: gnutls-3.3.29-8.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libnettle.so.4()(64bit) for package: gnutls-3.3.29-8.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit) for package: gnutls-3.3.29-8.el7.x86_64\n---> Package libproxy.x86_64 0:0.4.11-8.el7 will be installed\n---> Package libunwind.x86_64 2:1.2-2.el7 will be installed\n---> Package nginx-mod-http-geoip.x86_64 1:1.14.1-1.el7at will be installed\n---> Package nginx-mod-http-image-filter.x86_64 1:1.14.1-1.el7at will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: gd for package: 1:nginx-mod-http-image-filter-1.14.1-1.el7at.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.2()(64bit) for package: 1:nginx-mod-http-image-filter-1.14.1-1.el7at.x86_64\n---> Package nginx-mod-http-perl.x86_64 1:1.14.1-1.el7at will be installed\n---> Package nginx-mod-http-xslt-filter.x86_64 1:1.14.1-1.el7at will be installed\n---> Package nginx-mod-mail.x86_64 1:1.14.1-1.el7at will be installed\n---> Package nginx-mod-stream.x86_64 1:1.14.1-1.el7at will be installed\n---> Package pakchois.x86_64 0:0.4-10.el7 will be installed\n---> Package python-devel.x86_64 0:2.7.5-86.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: python2-rpm-macros > 3-30 for package: python-devel-2.7.5-86.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: python-rpm-macros > 3-30 for package: python-devel-2.7.5-86.el7.x86_64\n--> Running transaction check\n---> Package ansible-tower-server.x86_64 0:3.4.2-1.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: python-crypto for package: ansible-tower-server-3.4.2-1.el7.x86_64\n---> Package gd.x86_64 0:2.0.35-26.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: libXpm.so.4()(64bit) for package: gd-2.0.35-26.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libX11.so.6()(64bit) for package: gd-2.0.35-26.el7.x86_64\n---> Package nettle.x86_64 0:2.7.1-8.el7 will be installed\n---> Package python-rpm-macros.noarch 0:3-32.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: python-srpm-macros for package: python-rpm-macros-3-32.el7.noarch\n---> Package python2-rpm-macros.noarch 0:3-32.el7 will be installed\n---> Package trousers.x86_64 0:0.3.13-1.el7 will be installed\n--> Running transaction check\n---> Package ansible-tower-server.x86_64 0:3.4.2-1.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: python-crypto for package: ansible-tower-server-3.4.2-1.el7.x86_64\n---> Package libX11.x86_64 0:1.6.7-2.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: libX11-common >= 1.6.7-2.el7 for package: libX11-1.6.7-2.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libxcb.so.1()(64bit) for package: libX11-1.6.7-2.el7.x86_64\n---> Package libXpm.x86_64 0:3.5.12-1.el7 will be installed\n---> Package python-srpm-macros.noarch 0:3-32.el7 will be installed\n--> Running transaction check\n---> Package ansible-tower-server.x86_64 0:3.4.2-1.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: python-crypto for package: ansible-tower-server-3.4.2-1.el7.x86_64\n---> Package libX11-common.noarch 0:1.6.7-2.el7 will be installed\n---> Package libxcb.x86_64 0:1.13-1.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: libXau.so.6()(64bit) for package: libxcb-1.13-1.el7.x86_64\n--> Running transaction check\n---> Package ansible-tower-server.x86_64 0:3.4.2-1.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: python-crypto for package: ansible-tower-server-3.4.2-1.el7.x86_64\n---> Package libXau.x86_64 0:1.0.8-2.1.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Conflict: python-libs-2.7.5-86.el7.x86_64 conflicts python-virtualenv < 15.1.0-1\n--> Finished Dependency Resolution\n You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem\n You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest\nUploading Enabled Repositories Report\nLoaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager\n"]}

Comment: Hello, please add more details to your question. I'd format your error into a code block but there isn't enough info to do this.

Comment: Got above error while running './setup.sh', The deployment model is simple(i.e the web frontend, REST API backend, and database are all on a single machine).